# API call works when hard coded to localhost:3001/api/path but not when /api/path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, vercel

I am building a website on vercel using react and node.js. I have created an API request that call Google Sheets and returns some data. It can be found [here](https://www.humenergy.app/VPPFinder).

When deploying on local host, I deploy the node server on 3001 and the front end on 3000. The below function works successfully.

```
const checkEligibility = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/check-eligibility', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        // Include any necessary request body here
        body: JSON.stringify({ stateRegion, sectorOption }),
      });
      const jsonResponse = await response.json();
      setResponseData(jsonResponse);
      console.log(jsonResponse);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    }
  };
```

However when I deploy to vercel and change the function to:

`const response = await fetch('/api/check-eligibility',`  (i.e. remove http://localhost:3001), it stops working. I get the following error message:

> POST https://www.humenergy.app/api/check-eligibility 405 (Method Not Allowed)

However, the issue is not with the type of method allowed as it works when hardcoded, and I have tried other methods on postman and get the same message each time.

The API files are under a folder called server in the directory and I have the following server/server.js file:

```
require('dotenv').config();

const express = require('express');
const eligibilityRoutes = require('./routes/eligibilityRoutes');

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());

app.use(eligibilityRoutes);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

The route is defined in /server/routes/eligibilityRoutes.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { checkEligibility } = require('../controllers/eligibilityController');

router.post('/api/check-eligibility', checkEligibility);

module.exports = router;
```

I also have the following in /packages.json

`"proxy": "http://localhost:3001"`

How can I get it to work correctly. Do I need to alter some settings in vercel?

I've tried hardcoding the URL:

`const response = await fetch('https://www.humenergy.app/api/check-eligibility',`

but that doesn't seem to work.

Additionally when I have used postman to test the api I get the same error. I have tried several urls for the api (/check-elilgibility, /api/check-eligibility, /server/api/check-eligibility) but none work.

Answer (score 1):

Since both your frontend and backend are on different ports, essentially they are 2 different services. So when you use `'/api/check-eligibility'` and react usually run on `localhost:3000` it goes to the front end and never reaches your backend. There are 2 basic solutions for this:

1. You could host your backend on a seperate sub domain, say `api.humenergy.app` and then specify that on your front end
2. With NextJS you can write both backend and frontend, and use the `/api` route, though syntax for backend would change a little bit [Read Here](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/api-routes).

Comment: Thanks. I managed to fix it by renaming the server folder to api and changing server.js to index.js within the api folder.